# entity-framework error: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I got thiserror

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

only because this line

```
oldProject = db.Projectes.Find(project.ID);
```

**I need it in order to get the object before the edit, and afterwards compare the values changes between before and after the edit**, I do it in the third if statement (that compare one values), and in the "SFSiteEmailSend.ProjectEdited" function that only check the changes and send email about it.

By the way, I never change the "oldproject", the error still exist even if I delete all the email funcation and the third(last) if statement.

```
        // POST: /Project/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Project project)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {  

            // For Email Send - start
            string UrlProject = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Url.Action("Detail", "Project", new { id = project.ID });
            Project oldProject = new Project();
            Project newProject = new Project();
            newProject = project;
            oldProject = db.Projectes.Find(project.ID);
            SFSiteEmailSend.ProjectEdited(oldProject, newProject, UrlProject);
            // For Email Send - end

            if (oldProject.Finished == false && newProject.Finished == true)
            {
                project.DateFinished = DateTime.Now;
            }
            db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(project);
    }
```

Comment: I've run into this error message before.  In my case, it's because of the fact that EF adds all objects to the object graph.  So if I had attached items to a primary object (e.g. OrderLineItems to Order) and the ID's were 0, it would throw this error.  Make sure Project() doesn't instantiate any related objects.

Comment: What is the lifespan of your context? And does the error occur on the line `oldProject = db.Projectes.Find(project.ID);`? (_because this line_ is not clear about this).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is full of redundancy. Strip some of it out and it should become easier to spot the error:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Project newProject)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       string UrlProject = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) 
                         + Url.Action("Detail", "Project", new { id = newProject.ID });

       //both oldProject and newProject have the same Key but only oldProject 
       //is attached
       Project oldProject = db.Projectes.Find(newProject.ID);

       SFSiteEmailSend.ProjectEdited(oldProject, newProject, UrlProject);

       if (!oldProject.IsFinished && newProject.IsFinished )
          newProject.DateFinished = DateTime.Now;

       //now you try to attach another project with the same Key. 
       //It will fail when you call SaveChanges         
       db.Entry(newProject).State = EntityState.Modified;

      //This is an option:
      d.Entry(oldProject).State = EntityState.Detached;

      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   return View(newProject);
}
```

or you could load `oldProject` with `AsNoTracking` in the first place - as you already found out

Answer (score 1):

try 
project.entitykey = oldproject.entitykey 
before savechanges

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

Instead

```
public ActionResult Edit(Project project)
    {
     Project beforeEditProject = db.Projectes.Find(project.ID);
     .... 
    }
```

}

Use

```
public ActionResult Edit(Project project)
        {
          Project beforeEditProject = db.Projectes.AsNoTracking().First(p => p.ID == project.ID);
          .....
        }
```

Comment: This only evades the problem. The problem is that your context lives too long.

Comment: I don't think so, it's action noting make the context lives too long, this is not problem of context lives time

Comment: I believe using .Single is the better choice in this case.